# Children elements not visible in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have input my divs into container{ display: flex}. Once I get rid of display:flex it works fine and I can see my html. Also I found that if I change my percentage to px I can view my page.

Why is this ?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: .2%;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
#one {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
#two {
  float: right;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 70.5%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="row">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, that's not valid HTML

Comment: I still have the same problem .

Comment: @Nick please (next time) try to format your code within a Snippet like I did (You have the Snippet button in your Editor tools) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
html, body{ height:100%;} /* not needed but good to have it */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*margin-top: .2%; /* why? it'll mess with vh100 adding scrollbars.. */
}
/*#container { you mean... */
#row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
#one {
  /* float: left; /* unnecessary, now parent is flex */
  background-color: black;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
#two {
  /* float: right; /* unnecessary, now parent is flex */
  background-color: grey;
  width: /*70.5%; you mean... */ 71%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="row">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You, I did not know floats would interfere with flexbox :)

Comment: Floats don't interfere with flexbox. They are simply ignored.

Comment: @Michael_B yes indeed (that's why I said *unnecessary* but thanks for pointing that out!)